# How can I change each duplicate set of values to different colour in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

I have a DataGridView with a Contact column full of numbers. Each number can reoccur multiple times,  or just once.
I am trying to find a solution to re-colour each set of rows that contain matching numbers, but not recolour the ones with no duplicates.
Example of the outcome I am trying to achieve:

```html
<p style="color:green;">2</p>
<p style="color:green;">2</p>
<p style="color:red;">3</p>
<p style="color:red;">3</p>
123 <br><br>
321 <br>
<p style="color:yellow;">4</p>
<p style="color:yellow;">4</p>
<p style="color:red;">3</p>
<p style="color:yellow;">4</p>
```

Here is my code, I think the problem is where I am incrementing the "duplicateCount" integer for the switch statement as I need it to increment only after every row containing the same value is coloured, but could not figure out a way to do that. Hoping I am clear enough and someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

```
    public void HighlightDuplicates(DataGridView grv)
    {
        List<String> alreadydone = new List<String>();
        int duplicateCount = 1;
        for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < grv.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow rowToCompare = grv.Rows[currentRow];
            for (int otherRow = 0; otherRow < grv.Rows.Count-1; otherRow++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = grv.Rows[otherRow];
                bool duplicateRow = true;
                string rowToCompareString0 = rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                string rowString0 = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                if (rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString() != row.Cells[2].Value.ToString())

                {

                    duplicateRow = false;
                    continue;
                    
                    
                }
                if (duplicateRow && currentRow != otherRow && !alreadydone.Contains(rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + rowToCompare))
                {
                    switch (duplicateCount)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            alreadydone.Add(rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + rowToCompare);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            alreadydone.Add(rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + rowToCompare);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            alreadydone.Add(rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + rowToCompare);
                            break;
                        default:
                            rowToCompare.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
                            row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
                            alreadydone.Add(rowToCompare.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + rowToCompare);
                            break;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            duplicateCount++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much in one go. Things get much easier when you split them up.
First get the distinct values (using linq and from memory):

```cs
var distinctValues = grv.Rows.Select(r=>r.Cells[2].Value.ToString()).Distinct;
```

Then write a method to assign the colours:

```cs
Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Color> AssignColours(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    // Add as many colours as you need here
    System.Drawing.Color[] colours = new System.Drawing.Color[] {System.Drawing.Color.Red, System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, System.Drawing.Color.Green, System.Drawing.Color.Purple};
    var result = new Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Color>();
    int currentColour = 0;
    foreach (var s in values)
    {
        result[s] = colours[currentColour++];
    }
    return result;
}
```

And finally call the method and set the colour of the cells:

```cs
var colourDict = AssignColours(distinctValues);
for (int row = 0; row < grv.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
{
    var cell = grv.Rows[row].Cells[2];
    var value = cell.Value.ToString();
    var backColour = colourDict[value];
    cell.Style.BackColor = backColour;
    cell.Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
}
```

**EDIT**
To not colour the unique values you need to change the expression to this:

```cs
    var values = grv.Rows.Select(r=>r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    var distinctValues = values.GroupBy(g=>g).Where(h=>h.Count()>1).Select(f=>f.Key).Distinct();
```

There might be a way to shorten that, but it works.
Then in the for-loop you need to take into account that the value might not be in the list:

```cs
var colourDict = AssignColours(distinctValues);
for (int row = 0; row < grv.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
{
    var cell = grv.Rows[row].Cells[2];
    var value = cell.Value.ToString();
    if (colourDict.ContainsKey(value))
    {
        var backColour = colourDict[value];
        cell.Style.BackColor = backColour;
        cell.Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have got it working now. Just have one issue, the values that are non-duplicates should be untouched, but are also getting a colour. I tried adding .Where to the end but it did not help
`var distinctValues = grv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => r.Cells[2].Value.ToString()).Distinct().Where(r =>r.Count() > 1);`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be over complicating things. It is unclear why your current code is using two `for` loops for this. One `for` loop will work and it will be less complicated.

The approach below simply loops through the rows in the grid and checks adjacent rows for equality. The only caveat here is that we need to color the first row FIRST. We know the first row will be colored since there is no “previous” row to compare it with.

Once this first row is colored, then we will loop through each row in the grid… HOWEVER, the `for` loop will not iterate to the LAST row. The loop will iterate to the second to the last row. With each iteration of the loop, we will check the “second” row to see if it equals the “previous” row and if so, we can color the second rows cell with the same color. If the cell values are not equal, then we will simply change the color of that cell to the next color.

It is unknown how many “different” colors you may want to use and, in the example below I used four (4) different colors and if the number of “different” cell values is greater than four (4), then we will simply start over with the first color used. In other words, the first and fifth groups of rows with “different” values will be colored the same and will repeat for every group of five different cell values.

To help, we will create a simple method called `SetCellColor` that will take an `int curColor` and a `DataGridViewCell cell`. In this method we will simply color the cell based on the given `curColor`. This method may look something like…

```
private void SetCellColor(int curColor, DataGridViewCell cell) {
  switch(curColor) {
    case 1:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
      break;
    case 2:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      break;
    case 3:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
      break;
    case 4:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Wheat;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Purple;
      break;
  }
}
```

This method above will make it easier to color the cell when we compare the two row’s cell values. We will use the above method in the method below which loops through the grid rows as described above. Keep in mind we need to set the loop to go from row zero (0), to the “SECOND” to last row. NOTE: this assumes the grids `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is set to `false`. If it is set to `true` then you will need to set the ending condition to Rows.Count – 2 to avoid a guaranteed `null` exception.

```
private void ColorDuplicateCells() {
  int curColorIndex = 1;
  SetCellColor(curColorIndex, dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2]);
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) {
      SetCellColor(curColorIndex, dataGridView1.Rows[i+1].Cells[2]);
    }
    else {
      curColorIndex++;
      if (curColorIndex > 4) {
        curColorIndex = 1;
      }
      SetCellColor(curColorIndex, dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2]);
    }
  }
}
```

Walking through the method, we color the first cell before we enter the `for` loop. Once in the `for` loop we compare the current row cells value with the next rows cell value. If the values are equal, then we will use the same color. If the values are different, then we will change to the next color by incrementing `curColorIndex` and then call the `SetCellColor` for the second row. Then continue on to the next row. In the `else` portion of the `if` statement, we need to check and make sure `curColorIndex` stays in bounds of the four (4) different colors. If the `curColorIndex` gets greater than four (4), then we will simply set it back to 1 and repeat the same color scheme for the rest of the rows.

I hope this makes sense.

***Edit update per OP comment...***

There are a couple of things that appear to be left out of you question. One question would be what do you plan on doing if the number of “duplicate” rows exceeds the number of “different” colors you use. In your example, you can clearly see the data and surmise that only four different (4) colors are needed. However, this may not always be the case and in my first answer I simply “repeat” the colors by repeating the four colors. This would mean that two or more rows of “different” values may have the same color.

Since I was under the impression the “different” values would be grouped together, then this strategy of repeating colors technically would work and still remove some ambiguity by the different values with the same color. Unfortunately, if the values are NOT “grouped” together, then ambiguity IS going to be an issue. In this case, with repeated colors, you could end up with two or more consecutive cells where ALL the values are different but the colors are the same…? …

The only way to avoid this ambiguity is to ensure that we have enough colors such that no color is used more than once. This is going to be dictated strictly by the data. This clearly points to looping through the data twice.

The first loop would be to figure out how many “different” colors are needed to avoid any ambiguity. How you do this is your call and, in the example below, the code sticks with the same strategy and simply repeats the colors if there are more “different” repeated rows than there are available colors… therefore ambiguity is guaranteed if there are not enough colors.

Next, it is unclear “how” the grid is getting filled with data. Typically, setting the grids `DataSource` to a `List<SomeClass>` or a `DataTable` is the preferred method to fill the grid with data. I will assume your code is “manually” adding the data directly to the grid cells and the grid does not use a data source. If this is true, you should re-think that approach to use a data source…

Casting UI `DataGridViewRows/Cell` to an enumerable type so you can select/filter/group the data is only extra work for you. If you use a data source for the grid, then selecting/filtering/grouping the `DataSource` as opposed to UI grid cells… becomes much easier and you can usually avoid the unnecessary casting of the UI cells. Bottom line, you need to do this grouping and counting using the DATA SOURCE NOT the grid cells. This is just a recommendation, pick your own poison. The example below uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid.

Given these issues, one approach is to loop through the data source `DataTable` to get a list of “different” duplicate rows. The approach you attempted sounds like a good approach… is what we want to get is a list of the row cell values that ARE duplicates. If a cell value is only used once, then, we do not want that value in the list. We can use this list to then loop through the grid rows and check each cells value to see if it is in the list. If it IS in the list, then that is a duplicate value and the cell needs to be colored. If the cells value is NOT in the list, then it is not a duplicated value and does not need to be colored.

The only problem here, is that we know the row is a duplicate… but what color should it be?... When we get the list of duplicate values, we need to assign a color to each of the distinct duplicate values. We could obviously create something to calculate this and in the example below, I simply used the index of the value in the list plus 1. Example, if the duplicate list has 5 items, then the first items (duplicate value) would be 0 + 1, the second item would be 1 + 1 etc.… this will enable us to use the same `SetCellColor` method created in the original answer and we do not have to create any extra variables.

The only change made to the method is I added a “default” value for the cells that are not duplicated. In that case we set the forecolor to black and the background to white. This will allow the code to color the non-duplicated cells to the proper colors. This updated method may look something like…

```
private void SetCellColor(int curColor, DataGridViewCell cell) {
  switch(curColor) {
    case 1:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
      break;
    case 2:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      break;
    case 3:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
      break;
    case 4:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Wheat;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Purple;
      break;
    case 5:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
      break;
        // more colors ?
    default:
      cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
      break;
  }
}
```

And finally, the code that puts all this together may look something like below. `duplicateItems` is a list of only the rows such that the values are duplicated… it gets its items using the LINQ statement with the `DATATABLE`… not the grid rows. This is the first loop through the data.

Then we start a second loop though the grids rows. `dupRow` will contain the item from the duplicate list that matches that rows value. If `dupRow` returns `null` then that value is not in the `duplicateItems` list and we set the color index to zero (0). If `dupRow` is NOT null, then that row is a duplicate and we can set the color index to the index of the item in the `duplicateaList` plus 1. Once the `colorIndex` is set we can call the `SetColorCell` method. This code may look something like below…

Note: `GridDT` is a `DataTable` that is used as a `DataSource` to the grid. The values column [2] is named “DupCol”.

```
private void ColorCells() {
  var duplicateItems = GridDT.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.ItemArray[2]).Where(y => y.Count() > 1).ToList();
  int colorIndex;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    var dupRow = duplicateItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(row.Cells["DupCol"].Value.ToString()));
    if (dupRow != null) {
      colorIndex = duplicateItems.IndexOf(dupRow) + 1;
    }
    else {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
    SetCellColor(colorIndex, row.Cells["DupCol"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've attempted to implement your code but i am having issues where only cells that are the same value and next to each other are coloured the same colour, whereas i need every cell that's the same value to be the same colour reglardless of position. that's why i was using the second for loop, to compare each column value to every other column value. There is a large chance I'm doing something wrong as I'm very new to coding in general.